# use elements of column recursively in data.table

Tags: r, list, recursion, data.table

Let's assume the following DT:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(n0 = c(550,575,550), age = list(c(5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2)), idx = c(16.63,16.39,16.22))
```

What I need to do is to calculate a new column using elements from existing columns recursively but haven't been able to figure it out the way to do it.

The new column must be calculated as:

```
n1 = n0 * (age2/age1)^-0.1429 * exp((-0.029+0.00144*idx)*(age2-age1))
```

- age1 should be: 5.2,6.2,7.2 (i.e. age[1:(length(age)-1)])
- age2 should be: 6.2,7.2,8.2 (i.e. age[2:length(age)])
- n0 initial is 550,575 and 550 but for the next item n0 should be replaced by n1 previously calculated.

So, for the first row, what I expect to get is: 550,534,520,508. For the second row: 575,558,543,531. For the last row, the expected result is the same as for the first row.

I can get the results using a for loop. What I would like to know if I can get the same by using DT more efficiently.

Comment: Fyi, you wrote `age2-age2` which is zero.

Comment: is there any particular reason you want age stored as a list inside a data.table rather than a set of subscripted vectors (age1, age2, etc.)?  I can't imagine that this structure lends itself to optimization in data.table.

Answer (score 0):

Will need a clearer picture to reconstruct the data.table but below is my interpretation of your data. Have reinterpreted the formula as a cumulative product instead of a recursion

```
library(data.table)

#will need a clearer picture to better re-construct the data.table
ages <- c(5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2)
test <- data.table(
    id = rep(1L:3L, each=length(ages)),
    n0 = rep(c(550,575,550), each=length(ages)), 
    age = rep(ages, 3), 
    idx = rep(c(16.63,16.39,16.22), each=length(ages)))

#create age1 by lagging age column
test[, age1:=shift(age, type="lag"), by="id"]

#calculate the term that is independent of prev recursion
test[, Val:=ifelse(is.na(age1), 1,
        (age/age1)^-0.1429 * exp((-0.029+0.00144*idx)*(age-age1))),
    by="id"]

#re-interpret the recursion as a cumulative product
test[, Result := n0 * cumprod(Val), by="id"]

test
```